# Connect to NAS device from Android

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, smb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cifs

I'd like to add NAS support to one of my application, and it is critical that the application is capable of streaming the content and that it not has to download it to the device. The application will be streaming video content, so once the video is over, there shouldn't be any large video files on the device.

**What I've tried so far:**

- **jCIFS** - Works beautifully, but isn't capable of streaming (to my knowledge). I've successfully created video files on the device using jCIFS, but they're still there, when the video playback stops.
- **Temporary files** - I know that Android is supposed to be able to support temporary files, but I'm not sure how it works or if it's any good in this situation. Just a thought, basically.

My application must be able to launch a video intent with a video on the NAS device, and it should be playable in any video player. I know that some applications on Market support NAS devices (and SMB / CIFS connections), but I don't know how it works.

Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create an in between http server as discussed in the following question: [Android ServerSocket programming with jCIFS streaming files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058135/android-serversocket-programming-with-jcifs-streaming-files)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing, already tried VPNC, no luck.
Now I am trying to use neo router my android can connect to the server but isnt able to browse any files. It might work for you. search for VPN setup (your router name here) android. It will give you some stuff to try.